# Selenium WebDriver ControlFlow execution

Tags: javascript, node.js, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I'm having a hard time getting a straight answer on the best way to write custom then-able functions (in JavaScript) using Selenium. I read that the entire ControlFlow implementation is based on Promises, so I incorrectly assumed that just including a promise within build in then-able commmands would be fine:

```
driver.findElement(By.css(""))
functionThatReturnsPromise()
driver.findOtherElement()
```

Up until now what I've been doing is this:

```
function() {
    return controlflow.execute(function() {
        return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
             // ...some logic here 
             resolve()
        });
    });
}
```

Which has worked, but one of two things is not necessary here: the (native) Promise, or the ControlFlow. I know it's not the ControlFlow because with just a promise things execute out of order.

It seems that passing any normal function to ControlFlow allows this to work as expected. Then I came across an issue saying ControlFlow is being deprecated in a future release:

https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium/issues/2969

If I am not supposed to be using ControFlow, what am I supposed to be using to create then-able custom functions that will properly execute in sequence?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution ended up being to abandon controlFlow, and resort to using the new async/await style like the example in https://github.com/airware/webdriver-mocha-async-await-example .

It still uses Promises under the hood, but in a native manner, completely eliminating the problem I was having before. 300 converted tests later, and I'm running smoothly with many fewer lines of code and much improved readability.